# Внешняя обработка для выгрузки данных зарплаты на сбербанковские карты в 1С Бухгалтерия 8.2

Tags: 1с

Я новичок в этом, уж извините) Но пытаюсь въехать. Взял шаблон обработки для ЗУПа. Выгружаю в dbf. Не могу понять, почему не выводит список сотрудников? Документы все есть и все проведены..(

```
Процедура КнопкаВыполнитьНажатие(Кнопка)

    ДБФ = Новый XBase;
    ДБФ.Кодировка = КодировкаXBase.OEM;
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("A","S",33);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("B","S",30);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("C","S",30);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("D","S",30);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("E","S",30);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("F","S",30);
    ДБФ.поля.Добавить("G","S",30);
    ДБФ.СоздатьФайл(ПутьКФайлу+"\f4683"+Строка(НомерВыгрузки)+".dbf",);

    //1
    ДБФ.Добавить();
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("A",Организация.ОсновнойБанковскийСчет.Банк); 
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("B",Строка(НомерПлатежногоПоручения)); 
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("C",перечисления.СпособыВыплатыЗарплаты.ЧерезБанк); 
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("D",Организация.ОГРН);
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("E",Организация); 
    ДБФ.Записать();
    //2
    ДБФ.Добавить();
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("A","Номер п/п");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("B","Номер счета");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("C","Фамилия");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("D","Имя");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("E","Отчество");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("F","Сумма");
    ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("G","Примечание");
    ДБФ.Записать();

    КоличествоЗаписей = 0;
    СуммаИтого = 0;

    Запрос = НОвый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст =
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Физлицо,
    |   ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Сумма,
    |   ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.Организация.ОГРН,
    |   ЛицевыеСчетаРаботниковОрганизации.НомерЛицевогоСчета,
    |   ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.Организация.ОсновнойБанковскийСчет.Банк
    |ИЗ
    |   Документ.ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизаций.Зарплата КАК ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата
    |       ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ЛицевыеСчетаРаботниковОрганизации КАК ЛицевыеСчетаРаботниковОрганизации
    |       ПО ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Физлицо = ЛицевыеСчетаРаботниковОрганизации.ФизЛицо
    |ГДЕ
    |   ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.Организация = &Организация
    |   И ЛицевыеСчетаРаботниковОрганизации.Организация = &Организация
    |   И ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.Организация.ОГРН = &ОГРН
    |   И ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.Организация.ОсновнойБанковскийСчет.Банк = &Банк
    |   И ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка В(&СписокДокументов)
    |   И ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.СпособВыплаты = &СпособВыплаты
    |   И ЗарплатаКВыплатеОрганизацийЗарплата.Ссылка.ПометкаУдаления = ЛОЖЬ";
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Организация",Организация);
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ОГРН",Организация.ОГРН); 
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Банк",Организация.ОсновнойБанковскийСчет.Банк);  
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("СпособВыплаты",Перечисления.СпособыВыплатыЗарплаты.ЧерезБанк);
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("СписокДокументов",ВыплатыЗаработнойПлаты.ВыгрузитьКолонку("Документ"));
    Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();
    СуммаИтого = 0;
    н = 0;  
        Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл 
        н = н +1;
        Если ПустаяСтрока(Выборка.НомерЛицевогоСчета) Тогда
            Сообщить("У сотрудника " + Выборка.ФизЛицо + " не указан лицевой счет", СтатусСообщения.ОченьВажное);
            НеФормироватьФайл = 1;
        КонецЕсли;
        Если Выборка.Сумма = 0 Тогда
            Сообщить("У сотрудника " + Выборка.ФизЛицо + " не указана сумма, перечисляемая на лицевой счет", СтатусСообщения.ОченьВажное);
            НеФормироватьФайл = 1;
        КонецЕсли;
        СуммаИтого = СуммаИтого + Выборка.Сумма;
        ФИО = Выборка.ФизЛицо.Наименование;
        Фамилия  = ОбщегоНазначения.ВыделитьСлово(ФИО);
        Имя      = ОбщегоНазначения.ВыделитьСлово(ФИО);
        Отчество = ОбщегоНазначения.ВыделитьСлово(ФИО);

        ДБФ.Добавить();
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("A",н);
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("B",Выборка.НомерЛицевогоСчета);
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("C",Фамилия);
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("D",Имя);
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("E",Отчество);
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("F",Формат(Выборка.Сумма,"ЧГ=6 ;ЧРД='.'; ЧДЦ=2"));
        ДБФ.Записать();
    КонецЦикла;

    Если НеФормироватьФайл = 1 тогда
        Сообщить("Файл не сформирован!", СтатусСообщения.ОченьВажное);
    Иначе
        //итог
        ДБФ.Добавить();
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("B","ИТОГО:");
        ДБФ.УстановитьЗначениеПоля("F",Формат(СуммаИтого,"ЧГ=6 ;ЧРД='.'; ЧДЦ=2"));
        ДБФ.Записать();

    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: А результат запроса какой?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что отладкой кода в 1С лучше заниматься самостоятельно.